# How to retrieve the attributes of a Bazel workspace rule using aspects

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

I'm writing a post-build tool that synthesizes maven pom files after a bazel build. I'm using *aspects* to gather relevant information on the various *targets*.

One of the features involves adding **external** jar dependencies to the relevant pom files.

Lets assume our ***workspace*** contains the following target:

```
maven_jar(
 name = "com_google_guava_guava",
 artifact = "com.google.guava:guava:19.0",
)
```

and one of our **BUILD** files contains a target which has *guava* as a dependency

```
scala_library(

name = "somename",
srcs = glob(["*.scala"]) + glob(["*.java"]),
deps = [
    "@com_google_guava_guava//jar:file" , 
],
```

In an *aspect* for this target how can one retrieve the attributes of *maven_jar*, specifically **artifact**?

(The closest I was able to get was:

```
[InputFileConfiguredTarget(@com_google_guava_guava//jar:guava-19.0.jar)]
```

Using `ctx.rule.attr.srcs`)

I could probably just parse the *workspace* external jars *targets* and get a map from the name to the *artifact* as a hybrid solution,

but a much more elegant solution would be for the aspect to provide the *artifact* by itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The "artifact" attribute is an attribute of a repository rule, which are not accessible from Skylark. The artifact seems like an information that could be integrated into the jar target in some way, feel free to file a feature request at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new, with the reason why you need that.

Comment: Thank you Damien for the clarification,
I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3120).